# Что за слово "айда"?

Tags: жаргон, этимология

Даже не знаю, можно ли отнести это слово к жаргону или сленгу. Там говорят между собой мальчишки (наряду с "пацаны" и т.д.). Речь о слове "айда", то есть, "пошли". А откуда оно вообще взялось? По звучанию напоминает тюркское.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По М. Фасмеру: айда́,гайда́ – межд., выражает восклицание, подгоняющее животных, вост.-русск., сиб. также адя́, укр. гайда́ – то же. Из тат. aida, äidä "понукающий, подгоняющий окрик", тур. haidä; см. Корш, AfslPh 9, 500; Вихман, Tschuw. Lehnw. 90; Mi. TEl. 1, 300; Радлов 1, 49, 669.

По Д. Ушакову: АЙДА́, межд. (·тюрк. ajda - эй! ну!) (·разг., ·обл. ). Пойдем, иди. Ну, ребята, айда за грибами!

Answer (score 5):

В современном татарском "айда" означает "давай", это обычное слово, не сленг.

Кстати, из татарского пришли и другие слова, например, сабантуй. У нас это ежегодный весенний праздник, со спортивными соревнованиями, празднуется в конце июня на воздухе.  А в русских городах (как я с удивлением узнала) это слово означает застолье.

Comment: Это аналог Курбан-байрама или самостоятельный праздник?

Comment: Не аналог. Курбан -переходящий праздник, а сабантуй - сезонный.

Answer (score 2):

В нашем, казахском, языке существует глагол "айда", что переводится как "веди". Коликтi айда - веди машину, бiздi айдабер - возглавляй нас(возглавь наше движение) и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Большой толковый словарь:

*АЙДА. [тат. айда]. Разг. I. межд. Употр. как решительный призыв, приглашение отправиться куда-л. Ребята, а. за яблоками! А., мужики, домой. II. нареч. в функц. сказ. Обозначает быстрое перемещение куда-л. Сел на машину - и а. в город! Наберём полные карманы каштанов - и а. обратно.*

Не жаргон и не сленг, а просто разговорный стиль

Answer (score 0):

Айда говорят детям когда зовут их идти куда-то. Первые шаги ребенка происходят под слова айда, айда. Мама татарка и бабушка говорят так. Своих детей тоже так же звал подойти ко мне. А вот моя жена татарка так не говорит и услышала это слово только от меня.

Answer (score -1):

Айда древнее слово.Ни откуда оно не приходило,а было всегда.Изначально звучало,как hайда,где hае-движение,да-согласие.Аналог-немецкое(вайда),тюркское-гайдар(всадник),английское гооуу..ХАЙДА(пойдем,двиГАЙ)говорилось с гортанным Г,как у украинцев,со временем звук-ХА слился в А.

Comment: Вот еще новый этимолог выискался(лась)

Answer (score -1):

Это из тюркских языков. В татарском языке это "әйдә" (айда) - пойдем, пошли. әйдәгез (айдагез) - во множественном числе.

Answer (score -1):

Айдар, хайдар, гайдар — тот, кто ведет, идущий впереди. Айда — веди.